# Working with expect command

Tags: expect

I have an installation script that gives out the following prompt:

Please type a selection or press "Enter" to accept default choice [1]:

I cannot make expect catch it. I tried to play around the equates surrounding Enter, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas would be welcome

Comment: See if `echo "" | /path/to/installation/script` will suffice, to send a newline to the command's stdin.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of problems with trying to match strings like `"[1]"`.

Firstly, `expect` uses `tcl` strings and `[]` are special characters inside double-quotes, so you either need to escape them with `\[`, or you need to use brace quotes `{}` instead.

Secondly, `expect` patterns are by default glob patterns, so  `[abc]` means match an a, b or c character. So you either need to escape the `[` a second time, or you can use option `-ex` to say you do not want to use a glob, but an exact string.

So the resulting command that should work is

```
expect -ex {default choice [1]:}
```